# How to run a JAR file through an icon on Java Desktop Application Using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, icons, desktop, jinternalframe

I want to execute a jar file (BORG Calendar) from an icon in a desktop application using java swing (JinternalFrame, JDesktoppane,...) But I dont know how?

Answer (score 3):

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can suggest desktop icons & menu items for a application.  I would recommend doing both, since from memory some OS' will disallow one or the other.

Alternately, JWS can leave the choice to the user, with the assistance of the [javax.jnlp.IntegrationService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html).

JWS is available for platforms that run Java, and is supported by Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your app using an icon in the desktop you have to export it as an executable jar file.

Here a tutorial how can you do it from the command line: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html

I suppose that you use an IDE for your programming, so you should have somewhere the option export as executable jar.

This is how i do it in eclipse:
[image]

Then find the jar file with the play icon.
[image]

I think that is all you need. You can optionally click on next and configure some more options. 
Note: Maybe your app uses external libraries or images that also should be added, dont forget about them.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: If so im sorry. I thought this is what you needed. Maybe edit the question so others don't get confused too. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to export your program as jar , then use a program like [Lunch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) if you want to make a shortcut to your jar .